# htaccess 404 redirect just showing page url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Can someone please help with my 404 redirect issue...

```
ErrorDocument 404 errorpgs/404.html
```

I've created a custom 404 page however when its called by a 404 error from my htaccess file, the only content shown on the page is the folder & file location of my custom html file.

Displays "errorpgs/404.html" and no other code or text, the address bar doesn't redirect and the title bar is just the browser default url bar.

The htaccess file is located in my website root folder and all other redirects are working fine.

Many thanks

Comment: Either try what `OlivierH` posted below or try the full http call e.g. `ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/errorpgs/404.html` and `.htaccess` is in fact in the root of your folder, right?

Comment: You should avoid to use external URL to handle HTTP errors. Why ? Cause this makes a redirection, and give a 302 HTTP code in the response. Crawlers and robots won't see the error and will think this is a normal page. Bad content will be indexed and non-existing pages will still be crawled and so available in Google, Bing etc.

Comment: Using the full url in the htacces 404 call does direct through to the custom 404 page but the original url address is lost, i wanted to keep it there as a reference... if that's at all possible?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
ErrorDocument 404 errorpgs/404.html
```

To

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errorpgs/404.html
```

Because apache takes this is as a message (ie string) to display, not a relative path to an html page. The slash indicates Apache this a path to a file.

Comment: Have previously tried with the preceding slash but that seems to ignore the condition altogether and shows the default browser 404 instead... Not Found The requested URL /URL-WAS-HERE was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Comment: Is your .htaccess file at the root of the web folder ? Same question for your 404 page.

Comment: My .htaccess file is in the root folder and my 404 file is in the "errorpgs/" folder which is also in the root folder.... i want the 404 error url to direct to the errorpgs/404.html page but with the erroring url in a parameter

Comment: linux server, but also trying this on my win7 localhost and not seeing which url is actually erroring, just the redirected url... using echo'<pre>'; print_r($_SERVER); echo'</pre>'; ?> to try and see the erroring url but this is only showing for the current page

Comment: This is normal, if you give an external url like `http://example.com/my_error_page.html`, apache makes a simple redirection. You can try to get `$HTTP_REFERER`, it may contains what you are looking for. But I'm still befuddled that a simple ErrorDocument is not working.

Comment: Thanks anyway OlivierH, i shall stick with the simple redirection for now as HTTP_REFERER was returning blank.